# Modal isn't functioning

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I want to create multiple modals that show image close ups with a opaque black background. The first modal "landscape_img_1" works perfectly. However, the second modal works, but just has the opaque black background without the image. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div id="myModal_1" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
<div id="myModal_2" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
</div>
```

```
<script>
    // Modal function 1
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal_1");
    var img = document.getElementById("landscape_img_1");
    var modal_img = document.getElementById("img01");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modal_img.src = this.src;
    }

    // Modal function 2
    var modal_2 = document.getElementById("myModal_2");
    var img_2 = document.getElementById("landscape_img_2");
    var modal_img_2 = document.getElementById("img02");
    img_2.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modal_img_2.src = this.src;
    }

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: One minor note - You forgot to use `modal_2` on the line `modal.style.display = "block";` for the second modal

Comment: Damn! I hate it when I overlook something like that lol. Thank you